# Is there a way to configure environment variables in a pod from a configmap created from a file?

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I have a config map that was created from an application.properties file:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  application.properties: |-
    datasource-url: xxx
    web-service-url: https://xxx
kind: ConfigMap
  name: my-configmap
  namespace: mynamespace
```

I would like to create environment variables from some of those values, e.g.:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "env" ]
      env:
        - name: SPECIAL_LEVEL_KEY
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: my-configmap
              key: datasource-url
```

However this doesn't work, it can't access the datasource-url property from the file.

Comment: is this a spring boot application?

Answer (score 1):

in your case it won't work since you define data as `application.properties` file. It needs to be `key:value` maps, see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-with-data-from-multiple-configmaps)

in your case:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  datasource-url: xxx
  web-service-url: https://xxx
kind: ConfigMap
  name: my-configmap
  namespace: mynamespace
```

Comment: I cannot change the configmap content...so it seems it not possible to do that